# How to show GridView in jQuery popup with GridView Paging?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm unable to show GridView in jQuery popup. GridView contains it's page index_changing event.

My .aspx code is below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="3" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
</asp:GridView>
<br>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnPopup" runat="server" onclick="lnkBtnPopup_Click">Show PopUp</asp:LinkButton>
```

CS code as below:

```
protected void lnkBtnPopup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = GetData();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = GetData();
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

jQuery as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[id*=lnkBtnPopup]").live("click", function () {
        $("#GridView1").dialog({
            title: "Image Details",
            width: "200px",
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>`
```

I want to show Grid with paging in jQuery popup when I click on LinkButton.
The code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are blocking the server-side click event handler `lnkBtnPopup_Click` from happening, because of this line in your script:

```
return false;
```

Remove this line and your server-side event handler will fire.

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for your reply. it's not working.... GridView is just showing in page, not in popup.

Comment: @TempExpt - put a `DIV` around the `GridView` control, set the `style=display: none;` and then reference the `DIV`'s ID in the jQuery `.dialog()` function.

Comment: hi, sorry for late response. anyway, it's working now. but when i click on next page then gridView disappeared. please help.

Comment: @TempExpt - is just the grid disappearing or the entire popup?

Comment: total entire popup disappeared. (one more thing: "return false;" is required). if "return false;" is removed then no popup appeared. i just keep "return false;" & add a div around Grid. then it's working. but in paging entire popup disappeared. & also when i click for next page it is postbacking(it's natural). can I go to next page with out total page page postback ?

Comment: @TempExpt - I believe the only way around your issue is to use an `UpdatePanel` so you can do a partial post back. Google "jQuery popup gridview updatepanel" and it should give you some leads.